# Using nextGen Gallery.. how can I call a list of all Gallery Names?

Tags: plugins, query, gallery

I'm trying to make a nav to access all the different galleries on a single page.

Instead of hard-coding all their names out. I was curious if it was possible to make this dynamic and just call all the ID's of all the galleries, with maybe an exclusionary on the two that are slideshows.

Anyone got any fresh ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All your Galleries are stored a table called `wp_ngg_gallery` in your wordpress database. (For the sake of completeness: nextGen Gallery creates 2 more tables for albums and pictures, respectively)

```
$gallery_ids = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT gid FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."ngg_gallery ORDER BY gid ASC", ARRAY_A);
```

fetches the IDs of all galleries into an array, ordered by ID from 1 to end. Now for excluding the two that are slideshows (the example will assume their IDs are 4 and 25):

```
$gallery_ids = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT gid
     FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."ngg_gallery
     WHERE gid NOT IN (4, 25)
     ORDER BY gid ASC", ARRAY_A);
```

What good are the IDs without the galleries' titles? Also, wouldn't it be easier to exclude by title? So this

```
$galleries = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT gid, title
     FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."ngg_gallery
     WHERE title NOT IN (slideshow_1, slideshow_2)
     ORDER BY title ASC", ARRAY_A);
```

would give you an array of all non-slideshow galleries ordered alphabetically by gallery title. You could also select with a wildcard `*` instead of `gid, title`, then you'd get all columns from the gallery table, which are *gid, name, slug, path, title, galdesc, pageid, previewpic, author*.

The resulting array is obviously meaningless unless you do something with it, such as iterating over it and creating a list of links.

The structure of the resulting array is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ['gid'] => 4
            ['title'] => 'playing_football'
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            ['gid'] => 8
            ['title'] => 'vacation_pics'
        )
)
```

You get the idea.

**EDIT: Creating a navigation from the above database query**

Assuming that you already have created pages for all galleries from within the *NextGen Gallery > Manage Gallery* dialog, the following will create a simple navigation from it. The *pageid* and *title* columns must have been selected from the databse.

```
echo '<ul>';

foreach ( $galleries as $gallery ) {
    echo '<li><a href="' .
         get_bloginfo( 'url' ) .
         '/?p=' .
         $gallery['pageid'] .
         '">' .
         $gallery['title'] .
         '</a></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

Reading, in case you care:

- [WP codex: `get_bloginfo()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo)
- [WP codex: `wpdb` class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)
- [php manual: Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
- [php manual: foreach loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Before you attempt to do something with the array, it is a good idea to dump it on screen and familiarizing yourself with its contents: `var_dump($galleries);` ([`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is God's gift to php developers...)

Comment: Johannes, this is the single best answer I've ever gotten. Thank you so much for your contributions to the community. I can't even tell you how thankful I am !

Comment: I was curious how I could echo this array. Or basically, how to call this object properly and display it?

Comment: @Trip Edited the answer to include an example for creating a simple navigation. I'm sure you can adjust it to your needs. In your code, the `echo` statement should probably a one-liner. I inserted line breaks after concatenation in the above only for legibility within this site.

Comment: Thanks again so much. This answer alone is going to be a cornerstone to **a ton** of my development. Thank you thank you thank you!!

Comment: You don't really need to manually query the db. That plugin has some basic API which you can use to get its data from the database. See for example find_all_galleries() in ngg-db.php

Answer (score 6):

Or more simply:

```
<?php

global $nggdb;
$galleries = $nggdb->find_all_galleries();
print_r($galleries);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs to add a menu of galleries using a certain album on a certain page can use my code.

```
<div id="gallery_menu">
        <?php

            // hardcoded part
            if(is_page(12)){
                $album_id = 2;
                $page_id = 12;
            }elseif(is_page(14)){
                $album_id = 3;
                $page_id = 14;
            }elseif(is_page(16)){
                $album_id = 4;
                $page_id = 16;
            }else{
                $album_id = 2;
                $page_id = 12;
            }

            // get the needed albums gallery id's
            $query = "SELECT sortorder FROM wp_ngg_album WHERE id=".(int)$album_id;
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                if($row['sortorder']){
                    $tmp = unserialize($row['sortorder']);
                }
            }

            // get gallery titles according to id's we got
            $query_titles = "SELECT title, gid FROM wp_ngg_gallery WHERE gid IN(";
            for($i=0; $i < count($tmp); $i++){
                if($i != (count($tmp)-1)){
                    $query_titles .= (int)$tmp[$i].", ";
                }elseif($i == (count($tmp)-1)){
                    $query_titles .= (int)$tmp[$i].")";
                }
            }

            // query and show titles with links
            $result_titles = mysql_query($query_titles) or die(mysql_error());
            echo '<ul class="gallery_titles">';
                while($row_titles = mysql_fetch_array($result_titles)){
                    echo '<li><a href="'.get_bloginfo('siteurl').'/?p='.$page_id.'&album='.$album_id.'&gallery='.$row_titles['gid'].'">'.$row_titles['title'].'</a></li>';
                }
            echo '</ul>';

        ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do not use `mysql_query()`, use the WP API instead.